# Should I create a class for a relation in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, orm

In Database, I have a `customer` entity and a `event` entity. There is a MANY-TO-MANY relation between them called `reserve`.

`reserve` has three columns, `CUSTOMER_ID`, `EVENT_ID` and `SEAT`.

The first two columns are primary keys of each entity. The third one is a relational attribute that's set specifically for the relation, so it is ONLY in the relation table.

What I am struggling is should I create a separate class for the `reserve` or should I do some trick in the two existing two classes to make this third one exist?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A many-to-many relation table must have only two attributes: the two primary keys of the tables that should be linked. In your case, since you store another attribute within that relation table, it's not a *pure* relation table and **you have to create a extra POJO for it**. As far as I know.

Comment: thanks a lot for answering! I just realized that I have been searching the wrong terms on Google, to everyone who searched to here, I think this might be the thing that you are looking for: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ManyToMany#Mapping_a_Join_Table_with_Additional_Columns